# gatsby-source-contentful access assets through local domain

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, contentful

**Goal:** To access assets using hyperlink through `example.com/...` instead of `images.ctfassets.net/...` or `assets.ctfassets.net/...`.

`gatsby-source-contentful` has an option `downloadLocal` which seems to do what I want. Yet, when I access the `url` field, it still shows the `ctfassets.net` path.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I made a stupid mistake by not specifying `gatsby-source-filesystem` in `gatsby-config.js`. After that, the `publicURL` field shows up.